Springboot CRON jobs: Add more service logic or use multiple repository fetch call?
My codebase has a cron job that fetches data somewhat like this pseudocode:
@Scheduled
@Transactional
    public void sendMessageRequest() {
           List<pm> pm1= pmRepository.findAllWithMessagesToSend();
           //logic on this data
           List<pm> pm2= pmRepository.findAllWithRemindersNotInWithStatus(pm1, Status.CREATED)
           for (PM pm: pm2) {
                    try {
                        NotificationType notificationType = null;
                        Integer reminderCount = null;
                        if (checkIfOneDayOld(pm)) {
                            notificationType = NotificationType.REMINDER_ONE;
                            reminderCount = 1;

                        } else if (checkIf2DaysOld(pm)) {
                            notificationType = NotificationType.REMINDER_TWO;
                            reminderCount = pm.getReminderCount() + 1;
                        }
                        if (notificationType != null) {
                        //more logic
                        pmRepository.save(pm)
            }
     }

the data maybe be atleast 1000s of records at times and this cron has to be run every 15 minutes.
Should I have the code like this or instead of doing a repository fetch call like this findAllWithRemindersNotInWithStatus, should I have multiple repository calls like findPMsForReminderOne, findPMsForReminderTwo etc.
Also should I save every pm within the loop or do a batch save at the end? Which would be faster for a CRON running every 15mins?


To Run the job for every 15minutes, you can set cron attribute to @Scheduled annotation. You can also define the timezone using zone attribute.
Example : @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * ? * * *", zone="EST")

Calling repository multiple times in code or fetching all at once and filtering them in code depends on your use case. But I will suggest you write multiple methods with scheduler annotation and in one method you can make one one repository call to get records which are 1day older and in another method you can make another repository call to get 2day older records and call a common method from both the methods to perform your custom logic.
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * ? * * *", zone="EST")
@Transactional
public void sendOneDayOldMessageRequest() {
   //Fetch 1 day old records from repository
   customelogic()
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * ? * * *", zone="EST")
@Transactional
public void sendTwoDayOldMessageRequest() {
   //Fetch 2 day old records from repository
   customelogic()
}

void customLogic() {
  //implement custom logic here. feel free to change return type if required.
}



By using above code, scheduler will pick the jobs parallelly for 1day and 2day old records for every 15miutes and process them.
You can also refer to https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html to form cron string of your choice based on your requirements.
